# codeigniter pass variable from controller to model

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, model, controller

simple issue I presume.

My controller is getting the if to display from the url using `$this->uri->segment(3)`. This will always be a single value. I am putting this in an array to pass to the model with:

```
$customerid = array(
   'id' => $this->uri->segment(3)
);
```

**The controller syntax is below:**

```
function confirm_delete_customer()
{
            $data['title']="Confirm Customer Deletion";

            $customerid=array(
                'id'=>$this->uri->segment(3)
                );

            //query model to get data results for form
            $data=array();

            if($query=$this->model_master_data->get_customer_records_to_delete()){
                $data['records']=$query;


            $this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_header",$data);
            $this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_nav");
            $this->load->view("master_data/view_content_master_data_confirm_customer_deletion",$data);
            $this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_footer");



}
```

I am then trying to access this array value and pass it to my model to process. If I hard code the array into the model it works as per below syntax:

**Model - Manual Syntax is:**

```
function get_customer_records_to_delete()
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('customers', array('id'=>43));
    return $query->result();
}
```

if I try replace this with the array from my controller it fails with error:
`Undefined variable: customerid`

**idea of model that I want to get working:**

```
function get_customer_records_to_delete()
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('customers', $customerid);
    return $query->result();
}
```

I have a feeling it is something small. however is this the best way to get a single record from the database in order to output to a view?

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do that is:

```
function confirm_delete_customer()
{
    $data=array();

    $data['title']="Confirm Customer Deletion";

    $customerId = $this->uri->segment(3);

    //Prevent SQL injections
    if(!is_numeric($customerId) || empty($customerId)) {
        show_error("Bad Request");
    }

    $query = $this->model_master_data->get_customer_records_to_delete($customerId);

    if ($query){
        $data['records']=$query;


        $this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_header",$data);
        $this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_nav");
        $this->load->view("master_data/view_content_master_data_confirm_customer_deletion",$data);
        $this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_footer");

    }
}
```

and then you can simply call:

```
function get_customer_records_to_delete($customerId)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('customers', array('id'=>$customerId));
    return $query->result();
}
```

at your model.

Comment: Thanks John. This works but is it best practice? I thought the controller should get the value and pass it to the model rather than the model getting the value directly?

Comment: Secondly, is this the best code snippet to use to return a single record? Thanks again John.

Comment: The answer is no, this is not the best practice. I will update the answer with a best practice technique.

Comment: Awesome, that makes allot of sense when I can read it, writing it is another issue :-) Thanks John, appreciate your time.

Comment: What is the whole prevent SQL injection part about? The model uses the query builder which automatically escapes the data.

Comment: I already know that. Also $this->uri->segment prevents the quotes as well. This was just an optional thing. It is just an example to actually filter the data before even go to the model. If your URL looks like this: /test/customer/acustomstring . This is actually a "Bad Request" and NOT a "Customer not found" Request :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the value as an argument to the function so it can access it.

Ex:

```
get_customer_records_to_delete($customerid)
{
    // now $customerid is accessible
    $query = ....;
    return $……;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should heavily rely on function parameters. Grab the customer id from the controller and send it to the model. Moreover, you can use `row()` to get a single result from the database.

**Controller**:

```
    function confirm_delete_customer(){
    $data['title']="Confirm Customer Deletion";

    $customerid=$this->uri->segment(3);


    //query model to get data results for form
    $data=array();

    if($query=$this->model_master_data->get_customer_records_to_delete( $customerid)) //you are sending customer id as a parameter here
    $data['records']=$query;


    $this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_header",$data);
    $this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_nav");
    $this->load->view("master_data/view_content_master_data_confirm_customer_deletion",$data);
    $this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_footer");



}}
```

**Model**

```
function get_customer_records_to_delete($customerid) 
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('customers', array("id"=>$customerid)); //you are using the customer id sent from the controller here
    return $query->row(); //this will return a single row
}
```

Comment: @Smudger I know it took me a bit to reply :D...but welcome anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but the answer is to declare the variable as "public" in the controller (i.e. `public $customerid;`), in which case it'll be available to your model. In some cases it's probably safer to explicitly pass as an argument. However, when you have several variables, it's useful to have the option to declare them instead.